# Pyspark DataFrame - How to use variables to make join?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having a bit of trouble to make a join on two Data Frames using Spark Data Frames on python. I have two data frames that I had to change the name of the columns in order to make them unique for each data frame, so later I could tell which column is which. I did this to rename the columns (firstDf and secondDf are Spark DataFrames created using the function createDataFrame):

```
oldColumns = firstDf.schema.names
newColumns = list(map(lambda x: "{}.{}".format('firstDf', x), oldColumns))
firstDf = firstDf.toDF(*newColumns)
```

I repeated this for the second DataFrame. Then I tried to join them, using the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

firstColumn = 'firstDf.firstColumn'
secondColumn = 'secondDf.firstColumn'
joinedDF = firstDf.join(secondDf, col(firstColumn) == col(secondColumn), 'inner')
```

Using it like this I get the following error:

> AnalysisException "cannot resolve 'firstDf.firstColumn' given input columns: [firstDf.firstColumn, ...];"

This was only to illustrate that the column exists in the input columns array.

If I don't rename the DataFrames columns I'm able to join them using this piece of code:

```
joinedDf = firstDf.join(secondDf, firstDf.firstColumn == secondDf.firstColumn, 'inner')
```

But this give me a DataFrame with ambiguous column names.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking don't use dots in names. These have special meaning (can be used either to determine the table or to access `struct` fields) and require some additional work to be correctly recognized.

For equi joins all you need is a column name:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

firstDf = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo")], ("firstColumn", "secondColumn"))
secondDf = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo")], ("firstColumn", "secondColumn"))

column = 'firstColumn'
firstDf.join(secondDf, [column], 'inner')

## DataFrame[firstColumn: bigint, secondColumn: string, secondColumn: string]
```

For complex cases use table aliases:

```
firstColumn = 'firstDf.firstColumn'
secondColumn = 'secondDf.firstColumn'

firstDf.alias("firstDf").join(
    secondDf.alias("secondDf"),
    # After alias prefix resolves to table name
    col(firstColumn) == col(secondColumn),
   "inner"
)

## DataFrame[firstColumn: bigint, secondColumn: string, firstColumn: bigint, secondColumn: string]
```

You could also use parent frames directly:

```
column = 'firstColumn'

firstDf.join(secondDf, firstDf[column] == secondDf[column])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, specially for the tip on not using dots in names. The first approach works, but I need the joined DataFrame to have unique column names for each column of the the two joined DataFrames. Using table aliases as suggested gives me the same AnalysisException error that I showed on the question, though.

Comment: It should work just fine. I added table definitions for a fully reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry mate, I just realized that changing the dot made it work. Thanks for the reply again!